# Undefined Columns Selected v. duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed

Tags: r, for-loop, vector, directory-structure

Within a for loop, I am trying to run a function between two columns of data in my data frame, and move to another data set every interation of the loop. I would like to output every output of the for loop into one vector of answers.

I can't get passed the following errors (listed below my code), depending on if I add or remove row.names = NULL to **data <- read.csv...** part of the following code (line 4 of the for-loop):

** Edited to include directory references, where the error ultimately was:

```
corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0) {
  source("complete.R")
```

**The above code/ my unseen directory organzation was where my error was**

```
  lookup <- complete("specdata")
  setwd(paste0(getwd(),"/",directory,sep=""))
  files <-list.files(full.names="TRUE") #read file names
  len <- length(files)   
  answer2 <- vector("numeric") 
  answer <- vector("numeric")
  dataN <- data.frame()
      for (i in 1:len) {
          if (lookup[i,"nobs"] > threshold){
               # TRUE -> read that file, remove the NA data and add to the overall data frame
               data <- read.csv(file = files[i], header = TRUE, sep = ",")
               #remove incomplete
               dataN <- data[complete.cases(data),]
               #If yes, compute the correlation and assign its results to an intermediate vector.

        answer<-cor(dataN[,"sulfate"],dataN[,"nitrate"])
        answer2 <- c(answer2,answer)
      }
    }
```

setwd("../")
  return(answer2)
  }

1) Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed

vs.)

2) Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , 2:3) : undefined columns selected

**What I've tried**

1. referring to the column names directly "colA"
2. initializing data and dataN to empty data.frames before the for loop
3. initializing answer2 to an empty vector
4. Getting an better understanding on how vectors, matrices and data.frames work with each other

** Thank you!**

Comment: Your code is not very effective and 'R-ish', but I think it should work. Did you make sure that you're reading a proper .csv file?

Comment: Thank you Marat. Yes, it is a proper csv file. (comma delimited text) What are some efficiency changes that you would recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that I had the function .R file that I was referencing in the code above, in the same directory as the data files I was looping through and analyzing. My "files" vector was an incorrect length, because it was reading the another .R function I made and referenced earlier in the function. I believe this R file is what created the 'undefined columns'

I apologize, I ended up not even putting up the right area of code where the problem lay.

*Key Takeaway: You can always move between directories within a function! In fact, it may be very necessary if you want to perform a function on all the contents of a directory of interest*

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

```
# get the list of file names
files <- list.files(path='~',pattern='*.csv',full.names = TRUE)

# load all files
list.data <- lapply(files,read.csv, header = TRUE, sep = ",", row.names = NULL)

# remove rows with NAs
complete.data <- lapply(list.data,function(d) d[complete.cases(d),])

# compute correlation of the 2nd and 3rd columns in every data set
answer <- sapply(complete.data,function(d) cor(d[,2],d[,3]))
```

The same idea, buth slightly different realization

```
cr <- function(fname) {
    d <- read.csv(fname, header = TRUE, sep = ",", row.names = NULL)
    dc <- d[complete.cases(d),]
    cor(dc[,2],dc[,3])
}
answer2 <- sapply(files,cr)
```

example of CSV files:

```
# ==> a.csv <==
#     a,b,c,d
# 1,2,3,4
# 11,12,13,14
# 11,NA,13,14
# 11,12,13,14
# 
# ==> b.csv <==
#     A,B,C,D
# 101,102,103,104
# 101,102,103,104
# 11,12,13,14
```

Comment: Thanks again @Marat I tried incorporating the second group of codes inside my if statement and for-loop. Now I am getting the error " Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names " which is slightly different from "undefined columns" selected. The first approach you mentioned aggregated my files, but I want to loop through each file individually, so I couldn't figure out exactly how to apply it to my scenario. I've looked at the different parts of my codes, and the nocol(data) is as I would expect. So I'm still stumped.

Comment: @Kara_F, Using the first approach, you can still look at every data set, they are just organized as the list elements. As you have trouble with read.table, I assume there is something wrong either with the name of the .csv file, or with its content.